# Adding GeoJSON layer Leaflet map?

Tags: geojson, leaflet

I am new to leaflet & its geojson features.

I am trying to test leaflet's functionalities and have built a map and its layer:

```
var map = new L.map('map', {scrollWheelZoom:true, doubleClickZoom:true, boxZoom:true, zoomControl:true});
var osmTiles = new L.TileLayer('http://localhost/googleapi/images/image1/tiles/{z}_{x}_{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 7,     minZoom: 3
}).addTo(map);
```

Now i want to draw a second layer (geoJson) upon it with a marker, so following the tutorila (cloudmate):

```
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON();
var geojsonFeature = {
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {
    "name": "Coors Field",
    "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
    "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
},
"geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [83.06877, -156.35742]
}
};
geojsonLayer.addData(geojsonFeature);
```

I am testing in my local PC (have not installed node + built leaflet) so maybe i am missing something.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the geojsonLayer to your leaflet map like you did with your tile layer with .addTo(map)

Comment: thanks! i have added geojson layer to map but the problem was wrong coordinates, since geojson uses inverse sequence for declaring coordinates (???) than leaflet... So the points did exist but i could not locate them.

Comment: I'm fairly new myself and what I do is create all of my features and attributes with QGIS and then save as a geojson file, (EPSG:4326). Havent had a problem yet.

Comment: Try setting attribute tms: true